# how I deal with this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in this noun finding program

Tags: java, parsing, nlp

I have came out with this problem that I couldn't find a way to solve this exception. Please do help.
My program is trying to find out nouns,verbs and adjectives from a user given sentence(Here I just tried to find out the nouns). If I had made errors in my program then please point those errors , so that I can correct it. 
Here is my code:

```
enter code here

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parse;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parser;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserFactory;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream;

public class ParserTest {

static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();
static Set<String> adjectivePhrases = new HashSet<>();
static Set<String> verbPhrases = new HashSet<>();
static String result;
gui_demo gd = new gui_demo();
String line = practice.gui_demo.textField1.getText();
public ParserTest(String line) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public ParserTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

//ObjectStream<String> lineArr = new PlainTextByLineStream(new StringReader(line));

String[] lineArr = line.split("."); 
public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
    if (p.getType().equals("NN") || p.getType().equals("NNS") || p.getType().equals("NNP") || p.getType().equals("NNPS")) {
         nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
         System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
    }

    if (p.getType().equals("JJ") || p.getType().equals("JJR") || p.getType().equals("JJS")) {
        adjectivePhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
         System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
    }

    if (p.getType().equals("VB") || p.getType().equals("VBP") || p.getType().equals("VBG")|| p.getType().equals("VBD") || p.getType().equals("VBN")) {
        verbPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
         System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
    }

    for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
         getNounPhrases(child);
    }
}


public void parserAction() throws Exception {
    try{
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
    for(int i=1; i <= lineArr.length; i++){
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(lineArr[i], parser , 1);      //getting Exception

    for (Parse p : topParses){
        //p.show();
        getNounPhrases(p);
    }
    }   
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    new ParserTest().parserAction();
    result = "Nouns :" +nounPhrases.toArray(new String[nounPhrases.size()]);//+ "\n" + "Verbs:" + verbPhrases + "Adjectives:" + adjectivePhrases;
    /*System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+nounPhrases);
    System.out.println("List of Adjective Parse : "+adjectivePhrases);
    System.out.println("List of Verb Parse : "+verbPhrases); */
    }

}
```

And the output of the program is:

> > java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
for(int i=1; i <= lineArr.length; i++) {
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(lineArr[i], parser , 1);
}
```

The last index of an array is always one less than the length of it, since the first index is `0` and not `1`. Therefore, `lineArr[lineArr.length-1]` is the last index.

You need to change `i <= lineArr.length` to `i < lineArr.length`.

Moreover, `i` starts at `1` and not `0`. If you do this you need to make sure your array has at least two elements, which you have not. You need to change this as well.

Final result should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < lineArr.length; i++) {
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(lineArr[i], parser , 1);
}
```